# TypeScript - wait a service that takes a callback and return "void"

Tags: typescript

For an application, I am using an external library which provide a service which takes arguments and callback. This service having a callback is not returning any promise. I would like to know if there is a clean way to wait for it other than an interval.

Here is a code snippet:

```js
class Foo {
    
    a: number = 0;

    constructor () { }

    public fakeService(data: number, callback: (sugestion:number, query:number) => void): void {
        // simulate the external service which takes a bit of time
        var b = 42;
        var a = 12;

        setTimeout(() => {
            return callback(data * a + b, 0);
        }, 500)
    }

    public update() {
        // call several services to get some data.
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let valid: boolean = this.getInfoFromService();
            if (valid) {
                resolve("OK " + this.a);
            } else {
                reject("NOK " + this.a);
            }
        })
    }

    private getInfoFromService(): boolean {
        // I need to call several time the service in parallel
        for (let i=0; i<5; i++){
            this.fakeService(i, (sugestion, query) => { 
                // the function to be run by the service once resolved
                // changes some class attributes
                this.a = Math.max(sugestion, this.a);
            });
        }

        return this.a == 90; // not working because services are not done yet
    }
}

const foo = new Foo();

// update should be a promise to trigger some other updates
foo.update()
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

I've tried to set the `getInfoFromService` as **async** and **await** the services but this is not working.

Thanks for your time and support,

Nicolas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I don't think this is something I can use (or I did not understand some answers). In the example I gave,  the **fakeService** replicates an external service that I cannot change (it is in fact a service inside a Microsoft Bing Library). In the response, (I think) they explain how to convert this function from callback to Promise.